# Converting jquery to good old fashioned js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the following in to `vanilla js`.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".savedPlayer", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let searchText = $(this).text().replace(" ", "%20");
  console.log(searchText);
  //resetState();
  //renderPlayerBtns();
  //searchBallDl(searchText);
  //searchYouTube(searchText);
  //searchGiphy(searchText);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='savedPlayer'>savedPlayer 1</div>
<div class='savedPlayer'>savedPlayer 2</div>
<div class='other'>other</div>
```

My particular questions are around the click event. Can js eventListener have more than one argument passed into it? What is the alternative in js to $(this)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `event.target` should be `this` if i'm not mistaking.

Comment: i could be wrong but from what i understand there is no alternative $(this) , its like saying if you dress up a person as a dinosaur in a made costume and then ask if you do not use that whats the alternative, well you would manually need to make the costume. saying that @Stutie answer looks gd

Comment: @Seabizkit the alternative would be to simply use `this.textContent` instead of `$(this).text()`.

Comment: @VLAZ that not really true... the one is a wrapper on an object which exposed JQuery conventions which "this".. would not have... aka if you tried to preform a JQuery 
 operation on "this"... it simply would not work. so depending on the complexity of what JQuery function or properties you trying to use, would then be the true tell which mean that would need to be specified in the question.

Comment: @Seabizkit and in this case, the code *only* calls `.text()` which is jQuery's proxy to `.textContent`.

Comment: @VLAZ 100% but that should form part of the question..... as it wouldn't always be the answer... eg `this.textContent instead of $(this).text()`  100% `this and $(this)` not so much as it largely depends on what you want to do, which mean each time the answer is different.

Comment: @Seabizkit the question is how to convert *this* code to vanilla JS. If the question is about how to do it *in general*, it would be too broad to answer because `$(this).text()` is nothing like, say, `$(this).draggable()`. There is no real good approach to explain how to convert both.

Answer (score 2):

As you are delegate `click` event to `.savedPlayer` you can do similarly with [`delegate` event](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

As it will invoke `click` event on every element inside `document` you need to check if it is correct target with `if (event.target.classList.contains('savedPlayer'))`.

You can replace `$(this).text()` with `event.target.innerText`. If you have used `$(this).htmk()` then use `event.target.innerHtml`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('savedPlayer')) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let searchText = event.target.innerText.replace(" ", "%20");
    console.log(searchText);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='savedPlayer'>savedPlayer 1</div>
<div class='savedPlayer'>savedPlayer 2</div>
<div class='other'>other</div>
```

---

**Edit** As per suggestion from @VLAZ Updated code to generalized delegate event.

```js
function delegate(eventName, selector, handler) {
  document.addEventListener(eventName, function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches(selector)) {
      handler(event);
    }
  });
}

delegate('click', '.savedPlayer', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let searchText = event.target.innerText.replace(" ", "%20");
  console.log(searchText);
});

delegate('click', '.other', function(event) {  
  alert(event.target.innerText);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='savedPlayer'>savedPlayer 1</div>
<div class='savedPlayer'>savedPlayer 2</div>
<div class='other'>other</div>
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in istening to clicks on the whole document and then checking if the clicked element has the desired class, compared to my answer?

Comment: @Benni yes, this will also handle the cases where DOM elements are dynamically added. With your approach the event binding happens once and any new DOM nodes added later will not have an event bound to them.

Comment: @Benni Your answer will be more `efficient` but if `element` is `created dynamically` then it will `not bind event` to newly created element. That is the reason for `delegate binding` is used. And as per `question` `$(document).on('click', ".savedPlayer", function(event) {` is also  `delegate binding` that why I have used the same.

Comment: Extremely minot improvement suggestion `event.target.classList.contains('savedPlayer')` -> `event.target.matches('.savedPlayer')`  it's slightly shorter and slightly more faithful to the jQuery way of doing it. Makes it easier to generalise this function later into `delegate(eventName, selector, handler)`

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for suggestion. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you add the listener to your 'savedPlayer' elements and access the clicked element inside the callback function:

```
document.querySelector('.savedPlayer').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function() {
        alert(event.target.innerHTML);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not "good old fashioned" JavaScript, as in the days jQuery was written, it did not have all the features you find nowadays, but this *is* a Vanilla JS Version of your snippet.

I realised the deferred event handling with a function that accepts a class name as an argument. Try it (only button "two" will react on a click):

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',evHandler("savedPlayer"));

function evHandler(cls){
 return function(ev){
  if (ev.target.classList.contains(cls)) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   let searchText = ev.target.textContent.replace(" ", "%20");
   console.log('action with: '+searchText);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<button class="test">one</button>
<button class="savedPlayer">two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

event.target is the alternative. It should look like this

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let searchText = event.target.innerHTML.replace(" ", "%20");
    ...
});
```

And for multiple arguments you can create a new function and call it in you onclick

Comment: Your event listener will trigger every time when any of `element` inside `document` is `clicked`. Also alternative of `text()` is `.textContent` or `.innerText`. `.innerHtml` will return `html tags` also.